# Haskell: Recursion with a polymorphic equality function

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Ok so we have not learned polymorphic functions yet, but we still have to write this code.

```
Given:
nameEQ (a,_) (b,_) = a == b
numberEQ (_,a) (_,b) = a == b
intEQ a b = a == b
member :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool
```

I added:

```
member eq x ys | length ys < 1 = False
               | head(ys) == x = True
            | otherwise = member(x,tail(ys))
```

but i get errors about not being the correct type as well as some other stuff. We have to see if an element exists in from some type. So we have those 2 types above. Some examples given:

```
phoneDB = [("Jenny","867-5309"), ("Alice","555-1212"), ("Bob","621-6613")]

> member nameEQ ("Alice","") phoneDB
True
> member nameEQ ("Jenny","") phoneDB
True
> member nameEQ ("Erica","") phoneDB
False
> member numberEQ ("","867-5309") phoneDB
True
> member numberEQ ("","111-2222") phoneDB
False
> member intEQ 4 [1,2,3,4]
True
> member intEQ 4 [1,2,3,5]
False
```

not exactly sure what i need to do here. Any help or documentation on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those errors you gloss over "about not being the correct type as well as some other stuff" are important.  They tell you what's wrong.

For example, the first time I threw your code into `ghc` I got:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a -> a -> Bool'
       against inferred type `(a1, [a1])'
In the first argument of `member', namely `(x, tail (ys))'
In the expression: member (x, tail (ys))
In the definition of `member':
    member eq x ys
             | length ys < 1 = False
             | head (ys) == x = True
             | otherwise = member (x, tail (ys))
```

Well, when I look at it that's straightforward - you've typed

```
member(x,tail(ys))
```

When you clearly meant:

```
member x (tail ys)
```

Commas mean something in Haskell you didn't intend there.

Once I made that change it complained again that you'd left off the `eq` argument to `member`.

The error after that is tougher if you haven't learned about Haskell typeclasses yet, but suffice it to say that you need to use the passed-in `eq` function for comparing, not `==`.

Comment: ok, i didn't know about the eq function. Yea i think i had that at one point and i kept getting errors (probably due to the ==). Thanks that helps.

Comment: @Matt: `eq` is not a library function you didn't know about--it's passed as an argument to the `member` function you wrote!

Answer (score 7):

Various things (I'm not going to write out the full answer as this is homework):

1. `length ys < 1` can be more simply expressed as `null ys`
2. You don't need brackets around function arguments.  `head(ys)` is more commonly written as `head ys`
3. You can, if you want, turn the top case and the other two into pattern matches rather than guards.  `member eq x [] = ...` will match the empty case, `member eq x (y:ys) = ...` will match the non-empty case.
4. You are using `==` for comparison.  But you're meant to use the `eq` function you're given instead.
5. You are bracketing the arguments to member as if this was Java or similar.  In Haskell, arguments are separated by spaces, so `member(x,(tail(ys))` should be `member x (tail ys)`.

Comment: For point 2: Not only are the parens there unnecessary, they'll actually fool you into believing that stuff is grouped in a way it isn't; for example, `foo a b(c)` is calling `foo` with three arguments, not with two.  What you probably meant then was `foo a (b c)`

Comment: Yea, we had to use what we were given. So member eq x (y:ys) was out of the question. But the null ys is helpful. Thanks. This does help.

Answer (score 2):

Since the parameters `a` in `member :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool`
don't derive `Eq`, you can't use `==` to compare them,
but instead have to use the given function `eq`.

Therefore your code might look like this:

```
member :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool
member eq x ys
 | length ys < 1 = False
 | eq x (head ys) = True
 | otherwise = member eq x (tail ys)
```

Only problem with this is, that length still requires to evaluate the entire List,
so you could reach a a better performance writing:

```
member' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool
member' eq x (y:ys)
 | eq x y = True
 | otherwise = member' eq x ys
member' _ _ [] = False
```

With the use of any you can simplify it even more:

```
member'' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool
member'' f a = any (f a)
```